# Is it possible to pass a function 'which return promise ' as a prop to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I create component could `MessageCreator`, Here is a snapshot how this component looks in browser

[image: Snapshot of how MessageCreator component looks in browser]

Now when user write message in this **textarea** and then click this **button** the message will send to server

- And while the message is sending I disabled the **textarea** and **button**
- Then when server returned successfully response:

  1. I make value of **textarea** empty
  2. I enabled **textarea** and **button**
  3. I show alert message say 'message sent successfully'
- But when server returned failed response

  1. I enabled **textarea** and **button**
  2. I show alert message say 'can not send message'

---

code of `MessageCreator.js` file

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const MessageCreator = props => {
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState("");
  const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = React.useState(undefined);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(false);

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (typeof props.onClickSend === "function") {
      setDisabled(true);
      props.onClickSend(message)
        .then(response => {
          setMessage("");
          setDisabled(false);
          setAlertMessage(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          setDisabled(false);
          setAlertMessage(error);
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {alertMessage && <div>{alertMessage}</div>}
      <form onSubmit={e => submitHandler(e)}>
        <textarea
          value={message}
          onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)}
          disabled={disabled}
        />
        <br />
        <button disabled={disabled}>Send Message</button>
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

MessageCreator.propTypes = {
  onClickSend: PropTypes.func
};

export default MessageCreator;
```

code of `App.js` file ( in this file I used `MessageCreator` component )

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import MessageCreator from "./MessageCreator";

function App() {
  const sendMessage = message => {
    // Code to send message to server
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // resolve("Message send successfully");
        reject("Error can not send message");
      }, 2000);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MessageCreator onClickSend={sendMessage} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code in Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-water-370sg?fontsize=14)

---

My question is does the technique (which I use it in `MessageCreator.js`) to handle `success response` and `failed response` possible. I mean this code:

```
props.onClickSend(message).then(response => {
  setMessage("");
  setDisabled(false);
  setAlertMessage(response);
}).catch(error => {
  setDisabled(false);
  setAlertMessage(error);
});
```

---

> **NOTE:** This is a simple component (I mean `MessageCreator` component) but I have another large component use same technique.
>
> So in short **My Question Is:** is it possible to pass a function (`which return promise`) as a prop to another component. (like that function which I pass it as prop to `MessageCreator` component)

Comment: You mean simply an "async function" or "a function which returns a promise", not "a function which returns an async function".

Comment: Yes, it's certainly possible. Doesn't it work?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, that's exactly what I wanted to say

Comment: Why are you asking if it's possible when you have already proven with your own code sandbox that it works? If you're curious about if the pattern is recommended, sure it's absolutely fine to do it that way.